# sending query from Android to php

Tags: php

I wrote a php file on Raspberry pi, using "$_Get" to receive query query strings including date('Y-m-d').
But I keep getting syntax error and I can't find out which part is wrong....

Here's my php code below:

```
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("220.133.21.50", "root", "120232", "weather");
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM dosensor ORDER BY num ASC';
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    $s="";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {$result = mysqli_query($connect, "Select * FROM dosensor ORDER BY num ASC WHERE `recordtime` 
          <='".$_GET["date('Y-m-d')"]."';");
          if ($s=="")  $s=$s."['".$row["recordtime"]."',".$row["DO"]."]";
          else $s=$s.",['".$row["recordtime"]."',".$row["DO"]."]";
        }
    }
```

And here's the query string sending from my Android Studio:

```
webview.loadUrl("http://"+intent.getStringExtra("ip")+":/linechart.php?
```

uid="+intent.getStringExtra("uid")+"&pw="+intent.getStringExtra("password")+"&date('Y-m-d') 
    AND recordtime >= date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-10 day'))");

Could someone tell my which part is causing syntax error?
the error should be on this line

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "Select * FROM dosensor ORDER BY num ASC WHERE `recordtime` 
<='".$_GET["date('Y-m-d')"]."';");
```

Comment: You did not tell what you sent. Nor did you tell what you get.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: connect in /var/www/html/linechart.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/www/html/linechart.php on line 19